# Next.js App on AWS Amplify: Build and Deployment "Succeeds" but does not end up displaying on site

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

I recently built a website in React that I realized should have been built in Next.js.
I had been deploying the app via AWS Amplify for a couple months, and without any problems.
However, after migrating all the files to a working Next.js app and deploying that via AWS Amplify, my build and deployment will still succeed but the running Next.js app will not be visible at the domain (which had been working fine for the React app).

Here are the logs from the frontend Build:

```
2023-12-03T10:17:07.254Z [INFO]: # Starting phase: preBuild
                                 # Executing command: cd next-fidelis
2023-12-03T10:17:07.263Z [INFO]: # Executing command: node -v
2023-12-03T10:17:07.268Z [INFO]: v18.17.0
2023-12-03T10:17:07.268Z [INFO]: # Executing command: npm install
2023-12-03T10:17:11.930Z [WARNING]: npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
2023-12-03T10:17:11.982Z [WARNING]: npm
2023-12-03T10:17:11.982Z [WARNING]: WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
2023-12-03T10:17:12.785Z [WARNING]: npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
2023-12-03T10:17:13.036Z [WARNING]: npm WARN
2023-12-03T10:17:13.036Z [WARNING]: deprecated rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
2023-12-03T10:17:13.135Z [WARNING]: npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
2023-12-03T10:17:13.981Z [WARNING]: npm WARN deprecated
2023-12-03T10:17:13.982Z [WARNING]: workbox-cacheable-response@6.6.0: workbox-background-sync@6.6.0
2023-12-03T10:17:14.688Z [WARNING]: npm WARN deprecated
2023-12-03T10:17:14.688Z [WARNING]: domexception@2.0.1: Use your platform's native DOMException instead
2023-12-03T10:17:14.955Z [WARNING]: npm WARN
2023-12-03T10:17:14.955Z [WARNING]: deprecated abab@2.0.6: Use your platform's native atob() and btoa() methods instead
2023-12-03T10:17:15.286Z [WARNING]: npm WARN
2023-12-03T10:17:15.288Z [WARNING]: deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
2023-12-03T10:17:16.257Z [WARNING]: npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-methods instead.
2023-12-03T10:17:16.258Z [WARNING]: npm WARN
2023-12-03T10:17:16.259Z [WARNING]: deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
                                    npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
2023-12-03T10:17:16.272Z [WARNING]: npm WARN
2023-12-03T10:17:16.273Z [WARNING]: deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
2023-12-03T10:17:27.794Z [INFO]: added 1760 packages, and audited 1761 packages in 20s
2023-12-03T10:17:27.795Z [INFO]: 252 packages are looking for funding
                                 run `npm fund` for details
2023-12-03T10:17:27.799Z [INFO]: 8 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 6 high)
                                 To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
                                 npm audit fix --force
                                 Run `npm audit` for details.
2023-12-03T10:17:27.823Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
                                 # Starting phase: build
                                 # Executing command: npm run build
2023-12-03T10:17:28.048Z [INFO]: > next-fidelis@0.1.0 build
                                 > next build
2023-12-03T10:17:28.621Z [WARNING]: ⚠ Invalid next.config.js options detected:
2023-12-03T10:17:28.622Z [WARNING]: ⚠     Unrecognized key(s) in object: 'future'
                                    ⚠ See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-next-config
2023-12-03T10:17:28.624Z [INFO]: ⚠ No build cache found. Please configure build caching for faster rebuilds. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-cache
2023-12-03T10:17:28.641Z [INFO]: Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
2023-12-03T10:17:28.642Z [INFO]: This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
                                 You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
                                 https://nextjs.org/telemetry
2023-12-03T10:17:28.721Z [INFO]: Creating an optimized production build ...
2023-12-03T10:17:30.656Z [WARNING]: Warning: For production Image Optimization with Next.js, the optional 'sharp' package is strongly recommended. Run 'npm i sharp', and Next.js will use it automatically for Image Optimization.
                                    Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sharp-missing-in-production
2023-12-03T10:17:38.470Z [INFO]: ✓ Compiled successfully
2023-12-03T10:17:38.475Z [INFO]: Linting and checking validity of types ...
2023-12-03T10:17:38.617Z [INFO]: Collecting page data ...
2023-12-03T10:17:39.916Z [INFO]: Generating static pages (0/12) ...
2023-12-03T10:17:40.420Z [INFO]: Generating static pages (3/12)
2023-12-03T10:17:40.473Z [INFO]: Generating static pages (6/12)
2023-12-03T10:17:40.541Z [INFO]: Generating static pages (9/12)
2023-12-03T10:17:40.643Z [INFO]: ✓ Generating static pages (12/12)
2023-12-03T10:17:40.793Z [INFO]: Finalizing page optimization ...
                                 Collecting build traces ...
2023-12-03T10:17:50.521Z [INFO]: 
2023-12-03T10:17:50.525Z [INFO]: Route (app)                              Size     First Load JS
                                 ┌ ○ /                                    16.3 kB         116 kB
                                 ├ ○ /_not-found                          882 B          81.5 kB
                                 ├ ○ /about                               137 B          80.8 kB
                                 ├ ○ /about/history                       1.64 kB        94.7 kB
                                 ├ ○ /about/team                          3.88 kB        97.2 kB
                                 ├ ○ /about/values                        1.65 kB        94.7 kB
                                 ├ ○ /blog                                764 B           114 kB
                                 ├ λ /blog/[slug]                         7.07 kB         120 kB
                                 ├ ○ /contact/book-introduction           1.17 kB        81.8 kB
                                 ├ ○ /icon.ico                            0 B                0 B
                                 └ ○ /solutions/sv-erp                    2.01 kB        95.1 kB
                                 + First Load JS shared by all            80.6 kB
                                 ├ chunks/472-4d5aa66bf325d594.js       27.5 kB
                                 ├ chunks/fd9d1056-c9f288aa9c64ccc3.js  50.9 kB
                                 ├ chunks/main-app-de1dee50347fb570.js  231 B
                                 └ chunks/webpack-737b11cb1da87ba1.js   1.97 kB
2023-12-03T10:17:50.525Z [INFO]: λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
                                 ○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
2023-12-03T10:17:50.581Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: build
2023-12-03T10:17:50.590Z [INFO]: ## Build completed successfully
2023-12-03T10:17:50.591Z [INFO]: # Starting caching...
2023-12-03T10:17:50.602Z [INFO]: # Creating cache artifact...
2023-12-03T10:17:50.605Z [INFO]: # Created cache artifact
2023-12-03T10:17:50.606Z [INFO]: # Uploading cache artifact...
2023-12-03T10:17:50.675Z [INFO]: # Uploaded cache artifact
2023-12-03T10:17:50.675Z [INFO]: # Caching completed
2023-12-03T10:17:50.677Z [INFO]: # No custom headers found.
2023-12-03T10:17:50.694Z [INFO]: # Starting build artifact upload process...
2023-12-03T10:17:52.684Z [INFO]: # Uploading build artifact '__artifacts.zip'...
2023-12-03T10:17:52.733Z [INFO]: # Uploading build artifact '__artifactsHash.zip'...
2023-12-03T10:17:53.177Z [INFO]: # Build artifact upload completed
2023-12-03T10:17:53.177Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2023-12-03T10:17:53.178Z [INFO]: # Uploading environment cache artifact...
2023-12-03T10:17:53.247Z [INFO]: # Uploaded environment cache artifact
2023-12-03T10:17:53.248Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

Thank you. Couldn't do it without Stack Overflow :)

[Passed all 3 stages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oE67y.png)

I tried playing with the Node versions at some points, but I really don't know what the issue is here. The logs appear to say everything was put together fine. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is it a caching issue? Can you see the changes on incognito?

Comment: Nope. Cleared cache and still not working. Thank you though.

Comment: ``` 2023-12-03T10:17:28.621Z [WARNING]: ⚠ Invalid next.config.js options detected:
2023-12-03T10:17:28.622Z [WARNING]: ⚠     Unrecognized key(s) in object: 'future'
                                    ⚠ See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-next-config``` 


These lines?